# finding target recipient in email

Tags: python, email

I am trying to get the recipient for an email message in Python. Using the email module works well when loading the message, and tipically one could use the "To" field to know that:

```
import email
msg = email.message_from_string(some_message)
print "recipient: {}".format(msg['To'])
```

But that won't work in many cases, such as when the recipient is the bcc field. I've been searching for the address and it seems to be coded in the "Received" fields.

as in the example:

```
In [25]: for l in msg.get_all('Received'):
   ....:     print l
   ....:     
[...]
from xxxx.xxxxx.com (xxxx.xxxxx.com [999.999.999.999]
    by xxxx.xxxxx.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id FFFFFFFFFF
    for <RECIPIENT@ADDR>; Sat,  4 May 2013 17:29:10 +0000 (UTC)
by xxxx.xxxxx.com with SMTP id 9999999999.9
        for <RECIPIENT@ADDR>; Sat, 04 May 2013 10:29:10 -0700 (PDT)
by 10.70.31.33 with HTTP; Sat, 4 May 2013 10:28:50 -0700 (PDT)
```

Is parsing this the correct way to know the recipient? Is there any way to parse that without having to implement a parser myself?

**edited**:

the `some_message` string in the example is (some data has been changed for privacy reasons):

```
From from@addr.com  Sat May  4 17:29:21 2013
Return-Path: <from@addr.com>
X-Original-To: script-99999999999999999999999999999999999@mx.xxxxxxxxx.com
Delivered-To: script-99999999999999999999999999999999999@mx.xxxxxxxxx.com
Received: from localhost (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
    by mx.xxxxxxxxx.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id FFFFFFF
    for <script-99999999999999999999999999999999999@mx.xxxxxxxxx.com>; Sat,  4 May 2013 17:29:21 +0000 (UTC)
X-Spam-Flag: NO
X-Spam-Score: -2.098
X-Spam-Level: 
X-Spam-Status: No, score=-2.098 tagged_above=-999 required=3
    tests=[BAYES_00=-1.9, FREEMAIL_FROM=0.001, HTML_MESSAGE=0.001,
    RCVD_IN_DNSWL_LOW=-0.7, T_DKIM_INVALID=0.5]
Received: from mx.xxxxxxxxx.com ([127.0.0.1])
    by localhost (yyy.xxxxxxxxx.com [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024)
    with ESMTP id EEEEEEEE
    for <script-99999999999999999999999999999999999@mx.xxxxxxxxx.com>;
    Sat,  4 May 2013 17:29:10 +0000 (UTC)
Received: from mail.zzzzzz.com (mail.zzzzzz.com [99.99.99.99])
    by mx.xxxxxxxxx.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id AAAAAAAA
    for <RECIPIENT@ADDR>; Sat,  4 May 2013 17:29:10 +0000 (UTC)
Received: by mail.zzzzzz.com with SMTP id wz19so1388292pbc.3
        for <RECIPIENT@ADDR>; Sat, 04 May 2013 10:29:10 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=zzzzzz.com; s=20120113;
        h=x-received:mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to
         :content-type;
        bh=2eA0+yYWPhD/5+hE3gbsF0Q7Y4kT0ZEPjnLAHCkmsqc=;
        b=ioHV7VqfAbClFrgdsafzlSOh/eoa3G0FEhMNTFlHcOMU+tq2a/9GMASbnsXYgH8dVr
         ZeHGV2Cpa0IPIt0sfr7mnJqsmzUSND1tYpWTnhcXn0b9II5FTScVRHTSigcDY6EvWZs2
         Cye/HCZtqnfjzVC/Vc5SrmDzap2yVNxUsMBzUrjRaoqrCH4/4FavilOJUaNYhI1XQela
         b1YLeh7GpmU1/CpnkAw4Dy6Hx4l7BDHYfvwA6pSuOwQb45KVdMzMOFCIKpIKRpwr5SVF
         TFrB+hZqULgEtyqluirFEw1HqPG7nn3Nq00ViX1P5o48tUlqx0M7hWbHOd7xxKfhQS/F
         3UxQ==
X-Received: by 99.99.99.999 with SMTP id x3mr19111157pbl.92.1367688550046;
 Sat, 04 May 2013 10:29:10 -0700 (PDT)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 99.99.99.99 with HTTP; Sat, 4 May 2013 10:28:50 -0700 (PDT)
From: "from@addr.com" <from@addr.com>
Date: Sat, 4 May 2013 19:28:50 +0200
Message-ID: <CBLwV1i-491fOX8KVhv3tr69mhqVCkZ=y44V0MwVJQpMPtfxN-Q@mail.zzzzzz.com>
Subject: prova2
To: undisclosed-recipients:;
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=bcaec52e5c2d30634004dbe7cee5

--bcaec52e5c2d30634004dbe7cee5
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

undisclosed
Carles

--bcaec52e5c2d30634004dbe7cee5
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

undisclosed<br clear="all"><div>Carles</div>

--bcaec52e5c2d30634004dbe7cee5--
```

Comment: What is `some_string`??

Comment: `some_string` is just the content of an email loaded from a file into a string.

Comment: I meant the value.. (`print some_string` one)